# Laradock - Running Redis queues with Supervisor throwing the error - Call to undefined function Moontoast\Math\bcadd()

Tags: laravel, predis, laradock

I'm running a Laravel project on Laradock. I have a Job class that handles a Notification class that sends mail. The Job uses Redis for the queue driver and everything is well set up

I have Supervisor all set up and working. Below is my `.conf` file that is executed by Supervisor when the Job runs:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan queue:work redis --sleep=3 --tries=5 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=8
user=root
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/worker.log
```

This is set up in Laradock's `php-worker>supervisord.d` directory. I also have Laravel Horizon set up to monitor my Redis queues. When the Job is executed, Supervisor runs the Job and this is confirmed in my `worker.log` file that logs the processing of the Job, as defined in the above `.conf` file, as shown below:

```
[2019-10-14 12:18:27][21] Processing: App\Jobs\NewStaffAdded
[2019-10-14 12:18:30][21] Processing: App\Jobs\NewStaffAdded
[2019-10-14 12:18:31][21] Processing: App\Jobs\NewStaffAdded
[2019-10-14 12:18:33][21] Processing: App\Jobs\NewStaffAdded
[2019-10-14 12:18:35][21] Processing: App\Jobs\NewStaffAdded
```

When i visit my Horizon dashboard, i find that the Job failed. Clicking on the failed Job to learn more details, i get this exception:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined function Moontoast\Math\bcadd() in /var/www/vendor/moontoast/math/src/Moontoast/Math/BigNumber.php:506
```

Looking aroud for possible solutions for the above exception, i see suggestions that the cause is absence of the **Bcmath** module for PHP but I've run the following command and confirmed I have this module:

```
dpkg --list | grep -i bcmath
```

Shows I have the **Bcmath** module for my PHP version(7.3). So don't know why I'm getting the mentioned exception, which is preventing my queue from being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was down to not having the **Bcmath** module in Laradock's **.env** file under the **PHP_WORKER** section set to **true**. Firstly the module has to be installed in your workspace, then turn it on under BOTH the **PHP_FPM** AND **PHP_WORKER** sections. My mistake was that i had only set true under **PHP_FPM** section so had to do the same under **PHP_WORKER** section